# Laravel: received password reset link with username instead of token

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm using the Laravel 5.8 built-in auth scaffolding. I was just trying the password reset functionality. I go to the route `password/reset` and I get the form where to insert my email address, I submit it and I correctly receive an email, but, the URL to the reset page contains the username of the user who requested the reset instead of the token.

Because of this, when I follow the reset link and I try to submit the form to reset the password I get a validation error massage which says that the token is worng, infact into the token hidden field the value is set to the username instead of the token, as arrives as parameter from the wrong URL. Inside the `password_resets` table there is the correct token which should be sent by email.

Inside the `web.php` file, `Auth::routes();` is at the top, so there shouldn't be any conflict with my routes.

Why Laravel is sending a wrong URL? What should I check?

Edit: Inside the `LoginController` the only thing changed is the overrided `credentials()` function:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    // This adds the check over the verify_token field upon login
    // the field must be null to pass the check
    return [
        'email'        => $request['email'],
        'password'     => $request['password'],
        'verification_token' => null
    ];
}
```

Comment: What have you changed? Can you share some code?

Comment: I've added some code. I also have to say that I'm using Socialite, but I doubt that it could be the cause.

Comment: And what about without your change? Does it work? Your change does not seems to mess with that code, but just in case you can try commenting out the method.

Comment: Just tried, same result.

Comment: Did you override username(), like mentioned in the documentation? or something in your User model?

Answer (score 0):

My bad (of course). I left this project for a few months and I forgot to have also overridden the email's template, I messed up with it. Thank you anyway for your time and sorry.